# can't run apps on any emulator

Tags: android, emulation

None of my applications will install properly on any emulator. When I try to run an application a message appears in the console window that it's installing a different application than the one I'm trying to run. Everything was fine yesterday and no changes have been made since then.

The emulator boots up and reaches the stage of showing a home screen. Then the launch is cancelled.

```
   [2013-05-20 16:27:56 - email app] New emulator found: emulator-5556
   [2013-05-20 16:27:56 - email app] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be        launched...
   [2013-05-20 16:28:50 - email app] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5556'
   [2013-05-20 16:28:50 - email app] Uploading email app.apk onto device 'emulator-5556'
   [2013-05-20 16:28:50 - email app] Installing email app.apk...
   [2013-05-20 16:30:58 - email app] Failed to install email app.apk on device 'emulator-5556!
   [2013-05-20 16:30:58 - email app] (null)
   [2013-05-20 16:30:58 - email app] Failed to install email app.apk on device 'emulator-5556': EOF
   [2013-05-20 16:30:58 - email app] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: EOF
   [2013-05-20 16:30:58 - email app] Launch canceled!
```

This happens whatever app I try to run.

I have read another solution to this that says that the app is installed in the emulator and you can run it directly from there. However, when I try to do this I get a message which says 'unfortunately the emulator has stopped'.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This seems work now by using run configurations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes Eclipse and other IDEs can get mixed up if you have files from several projects open. The best way to ensure that you are running the right app is to click on the project folder and then click run. You can also right click on the project and select run as.

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember that for the future. Though I didn't have any other projects open strangely.